# How do I invert and concatenate this map in a stack-friendly way?

Tags: clojure, stack-overflow

I have a hashmap:

```
(def x {:a [1 3] :b [2 4] :c [1 2 3 4]})
```

And I want to invert so each item of the input value is an output key and the value is the concatenation of keys in which it was found. e.g.

```
{1 [:a :c] 2 [:b :c] 3 [:a :c] 4 [:]}
```

I have one solution:

```
(defn invert [input]
  (apply merge-with concat
    (apply concat
      (map (fn [[k vs]]
        (map (fn [v] {v [k]}) vs)) input))))
```

Which works:

```
=> (invert x)
{3 (:a :c), 1 (:a :c), 4 (:b :c), 2 (:b :c)}
```

But fails for large inputs with a stack overflow:

```
=> (def big-x (apply merge (map (fn [i] {i (range 10)}) (range 10000))))
=> (invert big-x)

StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:49)
```

How do I accomplish this for large input?

Note, this is similar but different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451000/reversing-hash-map-in-clojure).

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Your `invert` works perfectly here on `big-x`. I tried it because I came to realise that [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25286418/1562315) is essentially a concise version of yours. Puzzling. Can you throw any light on this?

Comment: Maybe our JVMs' stack sizes are different. Mine's set to the default. I'm running in `lein repl`, not that should make any difference. I also tried outside a lein project, so there are no custom settings.

Comment: Solved! The problem was my naivety: testing with `(count (invert big-x))`, which I assume is not required to realise the value sequences. If you replace the first `concat` with `into`, the error vanishes. If I use `concat` instead of `into` in my solution, the error re-appears. Anyway, @mtyaka's solution will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks very much. Lots to think about next time I do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn invert [in]
  (reduce (fn [out [key vals]]
            (reduce (fn [o v] (assoc o v (conj (get o v []) key)))
                    out vals))
          {} in))
```

Comment: Great! It seems so obvious now. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Joe This solution is just like `reverse-graph` in the [graph contrib library](https://github.com/clojure/algo.graph/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/graph.clj), once you strip away the redundant graph defstruct: just in case you're looking for related algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, seems a bit complicated, but not overflow:

```
(defn invert-entry
  ":a [1 3] => {1 [:a] 3 [:a]}"
  [hash-entry] 
  (reduce #(if (%1 %2) 
             (update-in %1 [%2] conj) 
             (merge %1 {%2 [(key hash-entry)]})) 
           {} 
           (val hash-entry)))

(defn invert 
  [x] 
  (reduce #(let [single-inverted (invert-entry %2)] 
             (merge-with concat single-inverted %1)) 
          {} 
          x))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but mtyaka's answer is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a concise solution and have cycles to burn ...

```
(defn invert [m]
  (apply merge-with into (for [[k vs] m, v vs] {v [k]})))
```

For example,

```
(invert x)
;{4 [:c :b], 2 [:c :b], 3 [:a :c], 1 [:a :c]}
```

I've forgotten where I saw this (for sets, using `merge` instead of `into`), so I can't attribute it. It is not my doing.

---

I've now realised that if we rewrite your solution using `mapcat`, and replacing `concat` with `into`:

```
(defn invert [input]
  (apply merge-with into
         (mapcat (fn [[k vs]] (map (fn [v] {v [k]}) vs))
                 input)))
```

... it is effectively the same as the above.